# Right Array Division : Ignoring division by zeroes

Tags: matlab

I have two data matrices `A` and `B` of similar dimensions. I intend to divide each element of `A` by its corresponding elements of `B`. For this matlab provides a shortcut as `C = A./B`. However, `B` has many zero elements , for such elements I want elements of `C` to be zero rather than `NAN` . Does MATLAB provide a way to do this in an efficent manner? I could do this in a loop but that would be very expensive.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use logical indexing:

```
C = zeros(size(A));
t = logical(B);
C(t) = A(t)./B(t);
```

With logical indexing, only the elements of `A`, `B` and `C` corresponding to `true` elements of `t` will be evaluated. `t` is `true` only where `B` is non-zero. Note that `C` is pre-initialized to zeros to automatically take care of the cases that are not evaluated because `B` is zero.

Comment: +1 This avoids many unnecessary operations, as it divides by `B` only where it is non-zero