# Matlab- sparse- element wise division

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

Consider the following;

```
 A = [1 0 0; 0 2 0; 0 0 5];
 B = [2 0 0; 0 4 0; 0 0 10];
 A = sparse(A); 
 B = sparse(B);
 C = B./A
```

I expected `matlab` to do sparse operations only on non-zero entries. But it also does operation on zero entries and return`NAN`.

I saw few solutions in this site.

[1. Using logical indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532826/right-array-division-ignoring-division-by-zeroes)

```
>> c = B(logical(A))./A(logical(A))

c =

   (1,1)        2
   (2,1)        2
   (3,1)        2
```

As you can see, this does not preserve the sparse structure.

[2. Replacing output with zero, where A is zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877625/matlab-element-wise-division-by-zero)

This is an elegant solution if `B./A` is the only operation I do. What if I `B./A` is a part of a bigger operation? E.g `K = 3*(B./A)*rand(3) + 5*(A./B)*rand(3)`

Is there a simple way of dividing sparse matrices(having same structure) element-wise without  getting `NAN`?

Comment: what about `C=B./A;` `C(isnan(C))=0;` and then `K = 3*(C)*rand(3) + 5*(C)*rand(3)` ?

Comment: @shamalaia : https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/16445  This thread indicates that `C(isnan(C))=0;`  is not efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you index (logical or not), you need to index the result as well to preserve the sparse structure.

```
idx = find(A); %# assumes A and B have the same sparsity pattern!

C = A; %# initialize C to have the correct size and shape

C(idx) = B(idx)./A(idx);
```

Answer (score 1):

One more option:

```
B = spfun(@(x) 1./x, B);
C = A.*B;
```